# multiple columns together in where clause

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have one table subscription like below

**Subscription**

```
 user     user_id     cve_id         vulnerability_id    
 -------  ----------  -------------  ------------------- 
 kumar    17          CVE-2016-3987  74                  
 rajesh   16          CVE-2016-3987  74
```

I have another table like below

```
 APP_USER_ID     VULNERABILITY_ID     STATUS    
 --------------  -------------------  --------- 
 16              74                   assigned
```

I want to retrive all subscriptions which is not assigned to a user so far. I tried the below query

```
select * from subscription where user_id not in (select APP_USER_ID from app_user_subscription )
```

But it is skipping all the subscription if the user matches. I understood why it happened. Because I simply mentioned only `user_id`. I want to skip based on `user_id` and `cve_id`. How I need to update my query?

Comment: What is the point of having the user id and vulnerability id both appearing in the second table?  This does not look normalized to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The Subscription table what i mentioned above is actually a view. whenever there is an update in the other table I need that not to be reflected in the view. That's my objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the tables all rows will be returned, you can filter the unallocated ones by just returning rows with a null value using a `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT a.* FROM user u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN APP_USER_ID a on a.APP_USER_ID = u.user_id
WHERE u.user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Great. Simple clean answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from subscription where (user_id,cve_id) not in (select APP_USER_ID,<corresponding column for cve_id> from app_user_subscription )
```